# Получить информацию о другом процессоре

Tags: c, windows, kernel, драйвер

Пишу драйвер, соответственно использую функции из DDK. Есть функции, выдающие некоторую служебную информацию - меня конкретно интересует `KeGetPcr()`  (она выдаёт Pcr для **текущего** процессора). Но сейчас 99% компьютеров - многоядерные, а мне нужно получить это для **каждого** процессора/ядра, голову уже сломал как это сделать. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать или хотя бы - где про это можно прочитать?